# How can I zip every element of a nested list?

Tags: python

I have two nested lists:

```
l = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    ['d', 'e', 'f']
    ]
```

```
l2 = [
     ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
     ['d', 'e', 'f']
     ]
```

I want to merge every element of the two nested list into a new seperate list like this:

```
nl = [
     ['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c'], 
     ['d', 'd'], ['e','e'], ['f','f']
     ]
```

But my code:

```
r = []
r+= [[j + ' , '+ k] for j,k in zip(l[i],l2[i])]
```

Just gives me the last list in the nested list as result:

```
nl = [['f','f']]
```

How can I change my code to get everything in the two nested lists in nl ?

Comment: what is `i` in your code? You are using the variable `i` but it's never set

Comment: why was `['c', 'c']` skipped?

Comment: `nl` is a list that contains small lists with `two` elements each (e.g. `['a', 'a']`). But from your code, it looks like you want a list that contains small lists with `one` element each (e.g. `['a, a']`). Which is right?

Comment: Hi @rafaelc, I want two elements each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

l = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
  ['d', 'e', 'f']
]

l2 = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
  ['d', 'e', 'f']
]

nl = list(map(list, zip(chain(*l), chain(*l2))))
```

Output:

```
[
  ['a', 'a'],
  ['b', 'b'],
  ['c', 'c'],
  ['d', 'd'],
  ['e', 'e'],
  ['f', 'f']
]
```